Incorrect affiliation on publication
As the title says, I (and a coauthor) recently had our manuscript accepted at an IOP Science journal. The manuscript was published just a while back and we have noticed that our affiliations have been messed up. I belong to institute X (say) and my coauthor currently belongs to institute Y. However, the website and the publication assign both institutes X and Y to both of us. In the case of my coauthor, this is at least somewhat correct since when we started this work, he was affiliated to institute X (but shifted within a couple of months). In my case, however, this is completely wrong - I have only ever been at X and never at Y or any other place.
Is there a way to rectify this - or, rather, can this be rectified at all?
I am a Master's student and I will soon begin applying to graduate school - I am a bit worried about this being taken as academic dishonesty. In case, this doesn't get rectified, should I simply mention it on my C.V. next to the publication that the affiliation is assigned incorrectly?

Notify the publisher immediately and see what they say. They are the only people who can rectify the problem, after all. If they say yes, you're home free; if not, ask them if there's any alternative (they might be open to publishing a corrigendum).
As for your CV, there's no need to mention it, since it's not a major issue and especially since it might be fixed soon. If someone notices and asks you, then you can tell them that there was an error in the production process.

Well, I contacted them - hopefully, it can get rectified considering I got the publication mail just an hour ago.

@ShKol hang on to your email electronically (don't delete it), print out an additional copy and sign and date it and get someone to cosign it. You will likely never ever need it, and unless you give it to a lawyer to hang on (or get it notarized) it may not have legal standing. But in the remote possibility someone does bring it up in say a separate matter in order to "establish a pattern" (be it of dishonesty or carelessness) you can show that as soon as you noticed the problem you took steps to address it. Of course if the journal does take some kind of corrective action then all that's moot

I doubt that an honest, and very explainable error will have repercussions. You can ask the journal to correct the affiliation in their online version / information. A print version will not be changed.
A CV is compressed information. The wrong affiliation seems to be extraneous data. You probably have to create some form of narrative in your application, where you can mention the paper and "by the way, the institutional affiliation is messed up".
Errors should not happen, but they do. If belonging to Y is so prestigious, then the editor should have checked.

Well, since it got published just a couple of hours back, maybe there isn't a print version yet. I have contacted the journal in the meantime. To be frank, I had not considered the prestige part of it - but you're right, Y is indeed more prestigious than X internationally.
